# RequiresMTA equivalent in xUnit

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, xunit.net

I am porting some unit tests from NUnit framework to xUnit. Some of the tests, spins up additional threads. All these tests in NUnit are attributed with [RequiresMTA] attribute. I want to know, if there is an equivalent attribute or feature in xUnit? I tried going through the documentation of xUnit but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: It doesn't look like it. However, according to [this work item](http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9729): "In v2, all tests run in the MTA." (This is a pretty recent development.)